# 'this' keyword overriden in JavaScript class when handling jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, prototype

I have defined a class in JavaScript with a single method:

```
function MyClass(text) {
    this.text = text;
}

MyClass.prototype.showText = function() {
    alert(this.text);
}
```

Then, I defined a method that acts as a handler for a click event, using jQuery:

```
function MyClass(text) {
    this.text = text;
    $('#myButton').click(this.button_click);
}

MyClass.prototype.showText = function() {
    alert(this.text);
};

MyClass.prototype.button_click = function() {
    this.showText();
};
```

When I click the button, it fails saying:

> Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'showText'

It seems to be that `this` in jQuery click event handler refers the HTML element itself, and it does not refer the instance of the `MyClass` object.

How can I solve this situation?

jsFiddle available: http://jsfiddle.net/wLH8J/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's an expected behaviour, try:

```
function MyClass(text) {
    var self = this;

    this.text = text;
    $('#myButton').click(function () {
      self.button_click();
    });
}
```

or in newer browsers (using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)):

```
function MyClass(text) {
    this.text = text;
    $('#myButton').click(this.button_click.bind(this));
}
```

or using jquery [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
function MyClass(text) {
    this.text = text;
    $('#myButton').click($.proxy(this.button_click, this));
}
```

further reading:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: Excellent Yoshi, I'll give it a go to the $.proxy thing, it looks like the perfect solution to me, :-)

Comment: @antur123 You're welcome! The proxy is probably the safest bet regarding browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

`this` is determined when a function is called, not when it is defined. You have copied the function to the click handler, so when it is called it isn't associated with `MyClass` and `this` isn't what you want it to be.

You need to use a closure to store the value of `this` in a different variable.

```
function MyClass(text) {
    this.text = text;
    var self = this;
    var click_handler = function () { self.button_click(); };
    $('#myButton').click(click_handler);
}
```